# Display field names in Bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am using following Bibtex to generate the bibliography.

```
@inproceedings{ichinose:imcom17,
  title={Pipeline-based processing of the deep learning framework caffe},
  author={Ichinose, Ayae and Takefusa, Atsuko and Nakada, Hidemoto and Oguchi, Masato},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the 11th International Conference on Ubiquitous Information Management and Communication},
  pages={97},
  year={2017},
  organization={ACM}
}
```

Using ACM-reference_format, the output looks like

```
Ayae Ichinose, Atsuko Takefusa, Hidemoto Nakada, and Masato Oguchi. 2017. Pipeline-based processing of the deep
learning framework caffe. In Proceedings of the 11th International Conference on Ubiquitous Information Management
and Communication. ACM, 97
```

I would like to show the field names, here "page" before 97. How can I enable this?

```
Ayae Ichinose, Atsuko Takefusa, Hidemoto Nakada, and Masato Oguchi. 2017. Pipeline-based processing of the deep
    learning framework caffe. In Proceedings of the 11th International Conference on Ubiquitous Information Management
    and Communication. ACM, pages: 97
```

Comment: I assume the bibliography style you employ is called `ACM-Reference-Format-Journals` rather than `ACM-reference_format`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bibliographic entry contains an error: The field should not be

```
 pages={97},
```

Instead, according to https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=3022323, it should be

```
 pages = {97:1--97:8},
 articleno = {97},
 numpages = {8},
```

I.e., the piece is the 97th [!] entry in the book, and it is 8 pages long. Simply setting `pages=97` is not correct.

Using the `ACM-Reference-Format-Journals` bibliography style, one gets the following output. Observe the `Article 97, 8 pages` string. It would be quite incorrect to display `pages=97-105`...

[image]

---

For comparison, here's the output produced by the `plainnat` bibliography style. Note that the `pages` field is now displayed as `pages 97:1-97:8`.

[image]

(In order to make the outputs more alike, one might wish to comment out the `isbn` and `doi` fields in the code shown below.)

---

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
%%% see https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=3022323
@inproceedings{Ichinose:2017,
 author   = {Ichinose, Ayae and Takefusa, Atsuko and Nakada, Hidemoto and Oguchi, Masato},
 title    = {Pipeline-based Processing of the Deep Learning Framework Caffe},
 booktitle= {Proceedings of the 11th International Conference on 
             Ubiquitous Information Management and Communication},
 series   = {IMCOM '17},
 year     = {2017},
 isbn     = {978-1-4503-4888-1},
 location = {Beppu, Japan},
 pages    = {97:1--97:8},
 articleno= {97},
 numpages = {8},
 url      = {http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/3022227.3022323},
 doi      = {10.1145/3022227.3022323},
 acmid    = {3022323},
 publisher= {ACM},
 address  = {New York, NY, USA},
 keywords = {cloud computing, deep learning, distributed processing, 
             life-log analysis, machine learning},
} 
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,natbib}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format-Journals}
% or : \bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}
\cite{Ichinose:2017}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Depending the article or inproceedings, the format is different. Articles are not showing "pages" text while displaying page numbers. Can we make all reference types look alike?

Comment: @ProbirRoy - Why would you consider making all entry types "look alike"? For entries of type `@article`, the "pages" tag generally isn't shown because all readers -- at least, all readers who haven't been living behind a rock for the last 40 years -- will surely know that "55-66" refers to a page range. No need to supply utterly redundant information, right? In contrast, with entries of type `@inproceedings`, there are so many different possible numeric ranges that can show up in a formatted entry that it is non-redundant to supply the tag "pages".